# Problem Insert Data to connected tables postgresql

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.5

I have 2 existing tables: ***‘projects’*** and ***‘units’***.The two tables are connected through the project id. In the table ***'projects'*** the column is called ‘id’ and generates every time a new project is inserted. In the table ***'units'*** the same id is called ‘projekt_id’. 
I now want to add new projects from a third table that is called ***‘temp_units’***. That table also has information that is relevant for the table ***‘units’***. So for every row in the ***‘temp_units’*** table I want to create a new row in the ***‘projects’*** table and also a new row in the ***‘units’*** table. Those two rows should be connected through the projects id.
I tried the following query but I get the error: **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**. 
Then I read somewhere about adding Limit = 1, so I added that to the query below (it is shown as a comment there). 
With Limit = 1 the code worked but all of the inserted data in the ***‘units’*** table is connected to the first project created in the ***'projects'*** table.

At the moment it is like this:

projects

```
id
--
1
2
3
```

Units

```
Id | projekt_id 
---------------
 1 | 1 
 2 | 1 
 3 | 1
```

But I need it like this:

projects

```
id
--
1
2
3
```

Units

```
Id | projekt_id 
---------------
 1 | 1 
 2 | 2 
 3 | 3
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.19. I would really appreciate any help

```
WITH insert_projekte AS
    (
    INSERT INTO projects (name, projekt_status_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at)
    SELECT name, projekt_status_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at  
    FROM temp_units
    RETURNING ID
    )

INSERT INTO units (kgnr, ez, projekt_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at)
SELECT t.kg_ez, t.ez, (SELECT id from insert_projekte/*LIMIT = 1*/), t.creator_id, t.editor_id, t.inserted_at, t.updated_at
FROM temp_units t
RETURNING ID
```

Comment: In the second INSERT, you need to join the CTE results with the `temp_units` table. This probably requires more RETURNING columns.

Comment: But how does that work? I don't have an id in the temp_units table to join it with.

Comment: Is there really no mechanism at all to identify rows in `temp_units`? Is it possible that two rows are exactly the same?

Comment: I have to say I created the ‘temp_units’ table before out of a query, so I will add a new column with an id to that table. But after doing that I am still not quite sure how to fix it. Do I need more RETRUNING columns in the first or second INSERT?

Comment: I have tried it with `JOIN insert_projekte on t.id = insert_projekte.id` on the second INSERT. The query works but the the created projects still don't have the units data connected.

Comment: You need to join on whatever ID is the key for `temp_units`. This ID must be returned by `insert_projekte`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out eventually

```
        WITH insert_projekte AS
            (
            INSERT INTO projects (name, projekt_status_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at)
            SELECT name, projekt_status_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at  
            FROM temp_units
            RETURNING ID, name
            )
                        
INSERT INTO units (kgnr, ez, projekt_id, creator_id, editor_id, inserted_at, updated_at)
    SELECT t.kg_ez, t.ez, insert_projekte.id, t.creator_id, t.editor_id, t.inserted_at, t.updated_at
    FROM temp_units t
    JOIN insert_projekte on
    insert_projekte.name = t.name
    RETURNING ID
```

I always left the subquery in the second INSERT so it never worked before.
Thank you [@CL.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11397/cl) for the helpful suggestions.